# Swapping linked list elements

Tags: c++, linked-list

I try to swap two nodes in a linked list as follows:

```
void swapTwo(course*& first, course*& second)
{
    auto temp = first;
    first = second; 
    second = temp;
    second->next = first->next;     // error right here due to self-referencing
    first->next = second;
}
```

I got an error because second->next is already self-referencing.  Is there an elegant solution to this?  I can create 2 courses elements and re-construct first and second, but that seems so brute.  Thanks!

Comment: How big is the node's data element? You may be able to simply `std::swap(first->data, second->data);`

Comment: For this to work you have to access previous nodes. Turning this into doubly circular linkedlist would save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: Gentlemen (and ladies if any), I have figured that converting into vector, sorting, and converting back would save me a lot of trouble.  Heartfelt thanks your opinions and kindness.

Comment: @user4581301, I can see the reason of your answer.  It is pretty similar to creating 2 new elements and re-construct them.  Since the content of struct is not generic, -> data cannot be re-used.  Nevertheless, the logic is straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take multiple scenarios into account.

1. When the two aren't adjacent, nor is any of them the head or the tail
2. When they're adjacent
3. When either is the head or the tail
4. When one is the head while the other is the tail
5. When they're the only two in the linked list.

Comment: Thanks!  I figured I can just convert the linked list into a vector, sort, then convert back into linked list.  Way less headache that way.